# how to search for a list in a list and total up the amount and average

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = [
    (123, "hello", "english", 5.15,  125),
    (573, "nani", "japanese", 5.95,  100),
    (245, "ni hao", "Chinese", 3.95,  59)]
```

Hi, I having trouble getting the 125,100 and 59 from the list in a list.
I want to get this number 125, 100, and 59 from the list in a list and sum up the total and the average. (using python-3.x)

this list in a list 125, 100, 59 just an example, if I have more than this 3 value. so I need to know how to search for all the list containing this 125, 100, 59, ........

Please help me, thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @ProgrammingLearner. Do share a bit of code snippet of what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
total = sum([v[-1] for v in a])
avg = total/len(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
s = sum([x[4] for x in a])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the number is always at the last, you can use:

```
mean = sum([x[-1] for x in a)/len(a)
```